# How do I create a instance of a class using a variable?

Tags: actionscript-3, class, variables, methods

I am trying to pass a variable to a method in one of my Classes so I can use it to create the correct movieClip (image)

My Class code looks like this:

```
package  {
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.display.Sprite;


    public class SlideShow extends MovieClip{

        public function SlideShow() 
            {

                             //does something on start

        }

          //This function should take the string and use it as the class name below.
          public function addImages(BackGround:String):void
             {
            trace(BackGround);

            var main_bg:BackGround = new BackGround();
            addChild(main_bg);
                 }
         }
    }
```

and when I call the method from my maintimeline it looks like this:

```
var shoeSlide:SlideShow = new SlideShow(); 
shoeSlide.addImages("menPant");
```

SO `"menPant"` is acually the name I assigned to a class of a movieclip that has some images in it.

I am getting the following error:

```
SlideShow.as, Line 30   1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: BackGround.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make sure you import getDefinitionByName at the top of your class code if flash doesn't do it for you automatically.  This should work.

```
public function addImages(BackGround:String):void
{
    var symbol_class:Class = getDefinitionByName(BackGround);
    //EDIT: removed data type :BackGround -- this will give an error.
    var main_bg = new symbol_class();
    addChild(main_bg);
}
```

Comment: Great this is what I was looking for! +1 checked